# Svelte3/sapper/rollup exclude file pattern from compilation

Tags: configuration, rollup, svelte-3, sapper

I am trying to setup a TDD environment for an app I am building using svelte + sapper.

I need to ignore some files during the compilation (which uses `rollup` by default)... the reason why I need to exclude them is that I want to have a scalable scaffolding for my application, just like this:

```
src
|___components
    |
    |___aComponent
        |___aComponent.svelte
        |___aComponent.test.js
```

(e2e tests and integration will probably follow a different structure in order to maintain the `separation of concerns` and not to bound `route` and `component`.

The issue I am having right now is that `js` files are by default added into the project because of course I may need to create helper classes etc.

I already added `exclude: **/*.test.js`, but it looks like it's not enough...
here's my [configuration](https://pastebin.com/QECrhgWQ).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to exclude directories from compilation, but you can prevent them from being served, by using the [ignore parameter on sapper.middleware](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/229)

Answer (score 0):

This came up in a google search for me and is probably old, but in your exclude you have:

```
{
  exclude: ["node_modules/@babel/**", "**/*s.test.js"]  
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  exclude: ["node_modules/@babel/**", "**/*.test.js"]  
}
```